# Node-gyp options for make

Tags: makefile, node-gyp

When building a C++ project with *make*, I really like to use the "**-j**" option to use more cores to build the project.

When calling *node-gyp build [--debug]*, it calls *make* internally to build the C++ files. But can clearly see that each file is built one after another and as the project gets bigger, it gets longer.

Is there an option I could add in the *binding.gyp* or a way to call *node-gyp build* to specify how many cores I would like to use when compiling?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute, e.g.

```
export MAKEFLAGS=-j8
```

then it will be passed down in the environment and `make` will honour it,
unless something tampers with it on the way.

node-gyp itself uses the `JOBS` environment variable similarly, with `JOBS=max`
selecting as many cores as you've got.